# C++ derived class overloaded function (with std::function argument) not visible

Tags: c++, templates

Let me illustrate my question with following example. Suppose we have a base class that defines method *Exec* that takes one argument of any type (template). The method *Exec* calls then method *Call* that has been overloaded to take as an argument an std::function object with different parameters.

Now suppose we have a derived class that inherits after *Base* and overloads *Exec* so it takes as an argument yet another std::function object (with different argument set).

Something like:

```
struct Base
{
  template<typename Func>
  static void Exec( Func func )
  {
    Call( func );
  }

  static void Call( std::function<void(void)> func )
  {
    func();
  }

  /*other definitions of Call for other std::functions*/
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  using Base::Exec;

  static void Exec( std::function<void(int)> func )
  {
    func( 10 );
  }
};
```

Now suppose we want to call:

```
Derived::Exec( []( int i ){std::cout << i << std::endl;} );
```

this will give following compilation error (I tried with g++ 4.8.5 and 8.1.1):

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Call(main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>&)'
> ```

My question is: why does the compiler not see the definition of `Exec` in Derived class (`void Derived::Exec( std::function<void(int)> func )`)?
I would expect that during overload resolution the `Derived::Exec` will be chosen as it is most appropriate for the given argument:

```
 []( int i ){std::cout << i << std::endl;}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

*Lambda expressions* produce *closures* that have **anonymous** and **unique** types. These types are completely unrelated from `std::function`.

Your `template` is a better match as it can deduce the exact type of the *closure*. Invoking the non-`template` overload would require an `std::function` instance to be created from the *closure* (not an exact match).

Answer (score 0):

The lambda `[]( int i ){std::cout << i << std::endl;}` is convertible to `std::function<void(int)>` not to `std::function<void(void)>`.

Even when the template function in Base is being selected because of perfect match, inside of it you're passing `func` to `Base::Call` that accept something convertible to `std::function<void(void)>`, and the lambda is not. `Derived::Call` is never selected because of static dispatch, that's the reason of the error.